How to convert map[string]string to map[string][]byte in Golang
I have a map in Golang where the value is a string:
myMap := map[string]string{
  "key1": "value1"
  "key2": "value2",
}

I need to convert this to a map where the value is a slice of bytes instead of strings.
newMap := map[string][]byte{
  "key1": []byte("value1"), 
  "key2": []byte("value2"),
}

What is the best way to perform this conversion in Golang? I tried looping through the map and converting each string to a byte slice, but it doesn't seem very efficient. Is there a cleaner way to do a bulk conversion of the map values from []string to []byte?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

No, there is not. Basically, the underying logic is that strings are immutable, while byte slices are not, hence all type conversions between the two has to copy memory. You cannot have anything automated to do such things "in place".

Your types are wrong, the second is not map[string][]byte but rather map[string][][]byte (a slice of byte slices). If you want to convert a slice of strings to a singular slice of bytes, you'll first have to concatenate the string slice (strings.Join) and then convert that string to a []byte, but that looks wrong to me. Either way, iterating a map and casting string to []byte isn't that expensive, so just write the loop

@EliasVanOotegem, my take is that when the OP said "not very efficient", they meant programmer's effort ;-)

I have just fixed the types in the question, thanks!

So here is the function I use to perform this conversion, I hope this might help some other go programmers:
func convertToBytes(src map[string]string) map[string][]byte {
    if src == nil {
        return nil
    }
    dst := make(map[string][]byte, len(src))
    for k, v := range src {
        dst[k] = []byte(v)
    }
    return dst
}



A better model Go function: https://go.dev/play/p/F2_HpmBekaR

@rocka2q Can you explain how yours is better? Thanks.

@MarcLeBihan: It handles special cases, it preserves a nil map value in case it matters. It is efficient, it provides a precise make map capacity hint. For readability, it uses the familiar names from the Go standard library. For readability, it uses blank lines to separate code paragraphs, not code phrases. In summary, it has a better chance of passing a Go standard library code review.

Thanks @rocka2q, I update my answer to take in account yours!


What is the best way to perform this conversion in Golang?

The name of the language is "Go" and the best way is via some tiny bit of programming like what you already

[...] tried looping through the map and converting each string to a byte slice, but it doesn't seem very efficient.

What is "seem" here? Did you benchmark the code? Is this part of the hot path of your algorithm? If not: Why bother?

Is there a cleaner way to do a bulk conversion of the map values from []string to []byte?

No.

maybe you try to 'unsafe' to convert byte, it seems not to reallocate memory.
func string2Byte(data string) []byte {
    pstr := *(*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&data))
    h := reflect.SliceHeader{
        Data: pstr.Data,
        Len:  pstr.Len,
        Cap:  pstr.Len,
    }
    return *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&h))
}

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{
        "a":    "a",
        "byte": "byte",
        "b":    "b",
        "":     "",
    }

    res := make(map[string][]byte)
    for k, v := range m {
        res[k] = string2Byte(v)
    }

    fmt.Println(res)
}


unsafe: unexpected fault address 0x4afed4, fatal error: fault, [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x2 addr=0x4afed4 pc=0x4901d9]

I might need a sample to try since I don't have this problem locally.
